# I'm trying to make a stored procedure to verify a input integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a stored procedure to verify  a input INT  have maxim 15 digits and the first digit is not 0.

And now I have this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_verify_phone_numbers (@phone_number INT)
AS
   IF @phone_number > 15
   BEGIN
        PRINT 'Not ok'
   END
   ELSE PRINT 'OK'

   DECLARE @fld_id INT

   SET @fld_id = (SELECT LEFT(@phone_number, 1)

   DECLARE @result CHAR(25)

   SET @result = CASE 
                   WHEN @fld_id  > 0 
                     THEN 'OK'
                   ELSE 'Not OK'
END

PRINT @result
```

How can I put  together to verify this conditions?

Comment: Just an observation, but SQL doesn't seem like the right tool for that type of validation - should that validation be in whatever process collects the data?

Comment: I don't know ,maybe I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OUTPUT parameter to get pass or Fail status for passed values, Also use a BIT value like 1 for Pass and 0 for fail.

Also you are using Int data type for storing numbers and INT data type cannot accommodate a 15 integer long value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_verify_phone_numbers 
   @phone_number BIGINT  --<-- Int cannot hold 15 interger values
  ,@Result BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (LEN(@phone_number) <= 15) 
     BEGIN
       SET @Result = 1;  --<-- OK 
     END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
       SET @Result = 0;  --<-- Not OK 
     END
END
```

### Calling Procedure

```
DECLARE @Result_Rnt BIT
EXECUTE usp_verify_phone_numbers @phone_number = 1234567812
                                 ,@Result = @Result_Rnt OUTPUT
SELECT @Result_Rnt
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.

Comment: `LEFT(@phone_number, 1) <> 0` isn't needed at all

Answer (score 1):

since your input parameter is int database will eliminate a leading 0, so your check of @fld_id will always return OK.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_verify_phone_numbers (@phone_number nvarchar(100))
AS
DECLARE @longerthanfifteen int = 0, @startswithzero int = 0
  IF LEN(@phone_number) > 15
  BEGIN
      SET @longerthanfifteen=1
  END

IF LEFT(@phone_number,1)='0'
BEGIN
   SET @startswithzero=1
END

SELECT 
CASE WHEN @longerthanfifteen + @startswithzero > 0 
then 'Not OK' ELSE 'OK' END as Result
END
```

But I agree with the comment above that this probably doesn't belong on the SQL server, rather as validation in your input form